# Fullpath of current TCL script

Tags: tcl

Is there a possibility to get the full path of the currently executing TCL script?

In PHP it would be: `__FILE__`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`$argv0`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/UserCmd/tclsh.htm#M9)

Comment: if accessing from a procedure, either define argv0 as global, or fully qualify it as `$::argv0`

Comment: Note that the global `argv0` variable is a feature of tclsh and wish (and tclkit too) and not of Tcl in general. It's very common though; the support function `Tcl_Main` implements it for you…

Answer (score 16):

Depending on what you mean by "currently executing TCL script", you might actually seek [`info script`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm#M34), or possibly even [`info nameofexecutable`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm#M31) or something more esoteric.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to retrieve the name of the file that the current statement resides in, is this (a true equivalent to PHP/C++'s `__FILE__`):

```
set thisFile [ dict get [ info frame 0 ] file ]
```

Psuedocode (how it works):

1. `set thisFile <value>` : sets variable thisFile to `value`
2. `dict get <dict> file` : returns the file value from a dict
3. `info frame <#>` : returns a dict with information about the frame at the specified stack level (`#`), and `0` will return the most recent stack frame
   *NOTICE: See end of post for more information on info frame.*

In this case, the `file` value returned from `info frame` is already normalized, so `file normalize <path>` in not needed.

The difference between `info script` and `info frame` is mainly for use with Tcl Packages.  If `info script` was used in a Tcl file that was provided durring a package require (`require package <name>`), then `info script` would return the path to the currently executing Tcl script and would not provide the actual name of the Tcl file that contained the `info script` command; However, the `info frame` example provided here would correctly return the file name of the file that contains the command.

If you want the name of the script currently being evaluated, then:

```
set sourcedScript [ info script ]
```

If you want the name of the script (or interpreter) that was initially invoked, then:

```
set scriptAtInvocation $::argv0
```

If you want the name of the executable that was initially invoked, then:

```
set exeAtInvocation [ info nameofexecutable ]
```

**UPDATE - Details about: `info frame`**

Here is what a stacktrace looks like within Tcl. The `frame_index` is the showing us what `info frame $frame_index` looks like for values from `0` through `[ info frame ]`.

Calling `info frame [ info frame ]` is functionally equivalent to `info frame 0`, but using `0` is of course faster.

There are only actually `1` to `[ info frame ]` stack frames, and `0` behaves like `[ info frame ]`. In this example you can see that `0` and `5` (which is `[ info frame ]`) are the same:

```
frame_index: 0 | type = source | proc = ::stacktrace | line = 26 | level = 0 | file = /tcltest/stacktrace.tcl | cmd = info frame $frame_counter
frame_index: 1 | type = source | line = 6 | level = 4 | file = /tcltest/main.tcl | cmd = a
frame_index: 2 | type = source | proc = ::a | line = 2 | level = 3 | file = /tcltest/a.tcl | cmd = b
frame_index: 3 | type = source | proc = ::b | line = 2 | level = 2 | file = /tcltest/b.tcl | cmd = c
frame_index: 4 | type = source | proc = ::c | line = 5 | level = 1 | file = /tcltest/c.tcl | cmd = stacktrace
frame_index: 5 | type = source | proc = ::stacktrace | line = 26 | level = 0 | file = /tcltest/stacktrace.tcl | cmd = info frame $frame_counter
```

See:
https://github.com/Xilinx/XilinxTclStore/blob/master/tclapp/xilinx/profiler/app.tcl#L273

Comment: `info frame 0` should suffice instead of the longer `info frame [ info frame ]`. The zero refers to the current frame whereas the innermost `info frame` without arguments would return the number of the current frame.

Comment: Hi @cfi, this is a little counter intuitive, but [ info frame ] really starts with 1 and goes to [ info frame ]. 1 being the originating call and [ info frame ] being the most recent call. However, if you pass 0 into info frame, then you get the equivalent of [info frame [info frame]], which is the most recent call.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [file normalize] to get the fully normalized name, too.

```
file normalize $argv0
file normalize [info nameofexecutable]
```

Answer (score -3):

seconds after I've posted my question ... `lindex $argv 0` is a good starting point ;-)

Comment: I think you'll be disappointed with that. You'll get the first argument after the filename. If you do "tclsh foo.tcl one two" argv will be a list like ["one" "two"]