# How to get path of current script?

Tags: tcl

Sometimes its needed to get current path of a script. What are the ways to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While a script is being evaluated (but not necessarily while its procedures are being called) the current script name (strictly, whatever was passed to `source` or the C API equivalent, `Tcl_EvalFile()` and related) is the result of `info script`; it's highly advisable to normalise that to an absolute pathname so that any calls to `cd` don't change the interpretation.

Scripts that need the information tend to put something like this inside themselves:

```
# This is a *good* use of [variable]…
variable myLocation [file normalize [info script]]
```

They can then retrieve the value (or things derived from it) easily:

```
proc getResourceDirectory {} {
    variable myLocation
    return [file dirname $myLocation]
}
```

---

The other common locations are:

- `$::argv0` which is the “main” script (and you're evaluating the main script if it's equal to `info script`)
- `[info nameofexecutable]` which is the Tcl interpreter program itself (typically the `argv[0]` at the C level)
- `[info library]` which is where Tcl's own library scripts are located
- `$::tcl_pkgPath` which is a Tcl list of directories where packages are installed
- `$::auto_path` which is a Tcl list of directories where scripts are searched for (including packages! The package path is used to initialise this.)

Comment: A problem with this approach is that in nested scripts (where one script calls another) the `[info script]` call may refer to the currently executing script, and not the location of this call. Here is a way around that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838591/fullpath-of-current-tcl-script/24177213#24177213

Answer (score 15):

The best way I found to do that:

```
set script_path [ file dirname [ file normalize [ info script ] ] ]
puts $script_path
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try like this:

```
file normalize $argv0
file normalize [info nameofexecutable]
```

to get fully normalized name

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at http://wiki.tcl.tk/1710. The solution there also takes care of possible (multiple) symbolic links and points to the physical root location of the script.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case it does not work with "info script", you can do

```
regsub {/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$} $argv0 {} path
do $path/other_script_on_the_same_path_as_this.tcl
```

Now you will have the path of the current script on the variable $path.